# What is `fpath` in this Go/Revel controller?

Tags: go, revel

https://github.com/robfig/revel/blob/master/modules/static/app/controllers/static.go

What is `fpath` in the `import` declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a way to alias the package. Very cool.

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations